# TYPO3: Data is not posting on select file larger than 1.5 KB to be uploaded

Tags: php, file-upload, plugins, typo3, fluid

I need to upload files from the front in my plugin. I got the success with it, but then now I have an issue during uploading larger file than 1.5 KB. Whenever I select file larger than 1.5 KB, i get error:

## 1298012500: Required argument "newRockupload" is not set for Rock\RockUpload\Controller\RockuploadController->create.

[image]

So i have put this code in initializeCreateAction() of controller to debug:

$arguments = $this->request->getArguments();

DebuggerUtility::var_dump($arguments);

exit;

So whenever i select file which has lower size than 1.5 KB, I get posted data successfully in controller:

[image]

And whenever i select larger file than 1.5 KB i am getting nothing like this:

[image]

I tried and surfed lot. Need Help..

Comment: Are both files of the same type? Did you set up any file size limits in your Extension, PHP, TYPO3 or htaccess?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes both files are same type and i didn't set up any file size limits in htaccess, PHP or TYPO3 @PaulBeck

Comment: @SameerBhayani, not set up doesn't mean it doesn't not exist. Please check the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` PHP settings.

Comment: @PaulBeck yes, i have  set that variables in php setting and restarted apache too but still  it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you use POST or GET method? It sounds like a restriction of all form-data need to be below 2KB, so files should be handled outside anyway.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ yes i am sing POST method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it mentioned in the comments, this is probably an issue with the URL you are trying to send.

The parameter is not there in the TYPO3, (maybe not even on the server side.) I guess something is wrong with your fluid form.

You should inspect your request. 
You can check it in your browser / apache access log / even with a debugger in the TYPO3 code.

Probably you are trying to send the data of the file in the Request Header instead of the Request Body.

You have probably some characters already in your URL so a file > 1.5 kb exceeds the limit of around 2000 characters in the url.

See also here about the limit of the url:
[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Comment: Ok @Andras Otto
nice explanation